# Android webView call different URL when orientation changes

Tags: android, webview, android-orientation

I want to call differnt `URL`l when orientation changes from horizontal to vertical means different `URL` fro bath layout how can i do it ?..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //private static final String URL = "http://indiqo.eu/demos/storefront-mobile/";


    private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";


    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);


         final Activity activity = this;
         mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
             // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
             activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
           }
         });



        //refreshWebView();
         Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();

                int orientation = display.getRotation();

                if (orientation == Surface.ROTATION_90
                    || orientation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                     mWebView.loadUrl(URL);           
                } else {
                     mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
                }


    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
    .getDefaultDisplay();

int orientation = display.getRotation();

if (orientation == Surface.ROTATION_90
    || orientation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
    URL = "[your landscape url]";            
} else {
    URL = "[your portrait url]";
}
```

Comment: Wherever you are setting your URL parameter

Comment: shoudl i call it inside oncreate or before oncreate

Comment: Inside onCreate. If you have any trouble, then edit your question to show the code you are using.

Comment: updated getting error at this line "Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
        .getDefaultDisplay();"

Comment: Have you imported "android.view.WindowManager"? - if you post your full code, then I will be able to see what you have done (or haven't done!)